# Distinct column value in C# DataTable

Tags: c#, loops, datatable

I have a DataTable in C# that looks like the following.

```
ID | Name | foodEaten | amountEaten
1  | Sam  | Burger    |   3
2  | Jeff | Burger    |   2
3  |Steve | Burger    |   1
4  |Clive | Mcdonalds |   4   
5  |Mike  | KFC       |   12 
6  |Cliff | KFC       |   5
```

Im trying to basically output it to HTML via, using webforms. The issue is, the output could always vary, but it will always need to group on the foodEaten.

What im after is basically a way to group the results on the foodEaten column, but then write out those who ate the food underneath. I just need pointing in the right direction of how I can dynamically assign this to a asp:repeater. Or something similar.

Ideally it would look like this on the page -

```
 <h3> Burger(3)<h3>
 <p> Sam - 3 <p>
 <p> Jeff - 2 <p>
 <p> Steve - 1 <p>
```

Thanks

Sam

Edit -

I now have a distinct values datatable which contains the distinct foodEaten values! Now to work out how to compare.

Edit2 -

I now have a DataSet that contains the distinct 'foodEaten' Values as table names, and the respective rows in each table, based on the foodEaten column. Now I just need to bind that, dynmaically to a repeater!

Comment: What do you mean by "Now to work out how to compare"? What are you comparing?

Comment: The distinct values table and the full table!

Comment: Are you familiar with nested repeaters? You can use one repeater for the foodEaten group (Ex: Burger (3)) then use a nested repeater to loop through the persons that ate that food. You may need to create an object to store the list instead of only using a dataset.

Comment: I thought about this, but wont I have the issue of this not being dynamic? Wont i need to hardcode table names and whatnot?

Comment: See my updated answer. You don't NEED an object, and you can still be fully dynamic. Sneaky stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use LINQ because it is clean and easier than writing logic in a loop.

```
var groupedDT = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("foodEaten"))
                .Select(o => new
                {
                    food = o.Key,
                    personsCount = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("foodEaten") == o.Key).ToList().Count
                })
                .ToList();
```

This will return you a list of the distinct foods eaten with a nested list of the persons that ate that food with the amount they ate. You can access data (like Name) in a loop by doing something like `groupedDT[ foodIndex ].dataRows[ personIndex ]["Name"]`. Hope this helps.

====================================================================

** EDIT: Updated to show how this can feed to a nested repeater.

You need to add a ondatabound event to your main repeater. Then, when you bind your repeater, each item will fire the nested repeater binding. See below. Note: I also adjusted the LINQ to group the datatable so you can get just the count of persons (above).

aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repFood" OnItemDataBound="repFood_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <h3><%# Eval("food") + " (" + Eval("personsCount") + ")" %></h3>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfFoodEaten" Value='<%# Eval("food") %>' />

        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repPersons">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <p><%# Eval("[\"Name\"]") +  " - " + Eval("[\"amountEaten\"]") %></p>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code-behind:

binding main repeater:

```
repFood.DataSource = groupedDT;
repFood.DataBind();
```

ondatabound event:

```
protected void repFood_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var hfFoodEaten = e.Item.FindControl("hfFoodEaten") as HiddenField;
    var repPersons = e.Item.FindControl("repPersons") as Repeater;
    var dataSource = ViewState["DataTable"] as DataTable;

    repPersons.DataSource = dataSource.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("foodEaten") == hfFoodEaten.Value).ToList();
    repPersons.DataBind();
}
```

Adding a hidden field to the main repeater items is an easy way to pass the `foodEaten` variable to the nested repeater. Use this to get the data rows where the food matches. Then from the aspx, use `Eval` to grab the ID, Name, amountEaten, or whatever you need. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue, you could cast that table to Enumerable and then use Linq on it. Something like this:

```
var result = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row["Food"]).Select(grp => new
{
    Food = grp.Key,
    Eaten = grp.Sum(eaten => (int)eaten["amountEaten"])
});


foreach (var grp in result)
{
    log($"{grp.Food}  ->  {grp.Eaten}");                
}
```